# iOS: Run a single unit test from the command line

Tags: ios, tdd, xcode5, build-process, build-automation

I've been trying to find a way to run a **single** iOS unit test among multiple tests with the command line on an iOS device.

Here is ***what I've found*** thus far...

- I can use `xcodebuild test [options]` to build & run every tests.
- Found a tool called `xctest` in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin`. I've looked up in the man page and it is possible to run a single test. When I try using it, I get an error stating that I'm using x86_64 architecture and then a posix error pops after. This seems to indicate that it might be the `xctest` for Mac OS X apps.
- Found another `xctest` in for the iPhone Simulator.. but I want to run it on a ***iOS device***

I know that it is possible to select the tests I wish to run in a scheme, but this is problematic since I would need a very skillful & patient monkey to manually do this in a build system.

By the way, I am not using Apple's own Continuous Integration system with bots and using it is out of question because another build system is used for every other platform.

***My question is***: How can I run a single unit test (XCTest) from the command line with build automation in mind?

---

**P.S**: I don't have any code signing issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using xctool which can run tests on devices https://github.com/facebook/xctool